# Adding a gradient background to a scrollable UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, cagradientlayer

When adding gradients as backgrounds to views in iOS, I employ this method:

```
let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
// gradient settings...
view.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
```

However, when doing so on a **scrollable UITextView** the gradient is drawn only within the visible bounds which then **scrolls up and out of view when the text view scrolls up**.

Furthermore, as the **UITextView has no fixed content size**, it's also not possible to set the gradient to that, although that's not desirable either.

One workaround is to **place another view behind the scroll view** and apply the gradient there, then placing the text view over that and making its background transparent. **But this is not a preferred solution.**

**Q:** *Is there any way to fix the gradient layer position so that it doesn't scroll with the text layer?*

---

EDIT 1: *additional code:*

```
let view = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 20, width: 200, height: 200))
let gradient: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
gradient.frame = view.bounds
gradient.colors = [gradientColors]  // pre-set array of 2 CGColors
let alpha: Float = angle / 360  // pre-set between 0-90
let startPointX = powf(sinf(2 * Float.pi * ((alpha + 0.75) / 2)), 2)
let startPointY = powf(sinf(2 * Float.pi * ((alpha + 0) / 2)), 2)
let endPointX = powf(sinf(2 * Float.pi * ((alpha + 0.25) / 2)), 2)
let endPointY = powf(sinf(2 * Float.pi * ((alpha + 0.5) / 2)), 2)
gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(endPointX), y: CGFloat(endPointY))
gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(startPointX), y: CGFloat(startPointY))
view.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
```

---

EDIT 2: *workaround (working, **but gradient visible only after text view receives focus**):*

```
extension UITextView {      
  func addGradient(gradient: CAGradientLayer) {
    backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    let gradientContainer = UIView(frame:
      CGRect(x: frame.minX, y: frame.minY,
             width: frame.width, height: frame.height))
    gradientContainer.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    gradientContainer.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
    superview?.addSubview(gradientContainer)
  }
}

let view = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 20, width: 200, height: 200))
let gradient: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
gradient.frame = view.bounds
gradient.colors = [gradientColors]  // pre-set array of 2 CGColors
let alpha: Float = angle / 360  // pre-set between 0-90
let startPointX = powf(sinf(2 * Float.pi * ((alpha + 0.75) / 2)), 2)
let startPointY = powf(sinf(2 * Float.pi * ((alpha + 0) / 2)), 2)
let endPointX = powf(sinf(2 * Float.pi * ((alpha + 0.25) / 2)), 2)
let endPointY = powf(sinf(2 * Float.pi * ((alpha + 0.5) / 2)), 2)
gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(endPointX), y: CGFloat(endPointY))
gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(startPointX), y: CGFloat(startPointY))

view.addGradient(gradient)
```

---

EDIT 3: *creative workaround by **Carpsen90** (thank you!):*

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {

  @IBOutlet weak var myTxtView: UITextView!
  var gradient = CAGradientLayer()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    myTxtView.delegate = self
    gradient.colors = [UIColor.red.cgColor, UIColor.yellow.cgColor]
    updateGradientFrame()
    myTxtView.textInputView.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
  }

  func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
    updateGradientFrame()
  }

  func updateGradientFrame() {
    gradient.frame = myTxtView.textInputView.bounds
  }

}
```

This works quite well except:

*i. slight flickering caused by the gradient-refresh when typing*

*ii. carriage returns past the bottom of the text view sometimes cause the gradient to be displaced upwards resulting in a blank space at the bottom of the text view*

*iii. after typing past the bounds and having scrolled down beyond the text view bounds, the gradient remains affixed at the bottom of the **contentsize area** when scrolling up to the top of the text view; apparently scrolling does not trigger the **textViewDidChange()** delegate method.*

Comment: Please show more code of you setting up your textView and gradient.

Comment: You've said "this is not a preferred solution.". Why not? Sounds pretty sensible to me.

Comment: @sjwarner; I'm designing a UI-generator that instantiates controls programmatically. Accordingly, compounded or sub-classed controls are not preferable, although extensions are fine. If you have such a workaround, of course.

Comment: @iSofia are you setting the background of the textView using this `myTextView.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)`?

Comment: @Carpsen90, Yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a workaround: Make the VC observe the changes in the textView, and update the gradient frame accordingly:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var myTxtView: UITextView!

    var gradient = CAGradientLayer()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //set the delegate to self
        myTxtView.delegate = self
        //set up the gradient
        gradient.colors = [UIColor.red.cgColor, UIColor.yellow.cgColor]
        updateGradientFrame()
        //insert the gradient in the textInputView
        myTxtView.textInputView.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
    }

    //The textView delegate method
    func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
        updateGradientFrame()
    }

    func updateGradientFrame() {
        gradient.frame = myTxtView.textInputView.bounds
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, @Carpsen90. It's an elegant workaround, albeit with an ever so slight flickering. I'll keep this as an option and as the accepted answer soon. I've been tinkering with an extension that automatically adds a *UIView* directly behind the *UITextView* and then apply the gradient on the *UIView* and changing the *UITextView* background to *UIColor.clear*. So far the optics are correct, but I can't seem to get focus on the text view. I've tried bringing the text view to the front, but nothing seems to work. Any ideas on this?

Comment: @iSofia could you please post the code for this extension so that I could be more of help? Off the top of my head, you could try setting the `isUserInteractionEnabled` of this view to false, but it's just a guess.

Comment: Hey! That *(isUserInteractionEnabled)* did the trick! The text view is now able to get focus. Thank you. But one more thing, though; When the text view is first displayed, the gradient is not visible, but becomes visible only when the text view receives focus. I can't figure this one out.

Comment: I've just updated the OP with the code for this workaround.

Comment: @iSofia make sure to send that view to the back : put the following line in your extension `superview?.sendSubview(toBack: gradientContainer)`

Comment: I tried both sending the gradient view to the back and bringing the text view to the front, but to no avail. The text view appears white, with just its border showing, and the gradient appears only when the text view receives focus. In fact, there are two text views in the same super view, and both their gradients appear even when only one receives the focus. *Strange, huh?*

Comment: Apparently you have more related code, and that makes difficult for me to reproduce the bug.

Comment: The frame of the `gradientContainer` is not right in my test project. Try your code in an empty test project. I don't have the focus issue.

Comment: *Focus issue?* But in your tests the gradient is visible when the view first loads, right? My text views are working correctly, able to receive focus, and the gradient stays put through all editing, scrolling, etc. **The only issue is that the gradient does not appear *at first* when the view loads.** I'll keep testing.

Comment: @iSofia yes I can see the gradient.

Comment: Still no luck with the gradient showing, *initially,* anyway *(it shows after the screen refreshes, like an orientation change)*. As for the `gradientContainer` frame issue you'd mentioned, I changed the `gradient.frame = view.bounds` to `gradient.frame.size = view.bounds.size` . It solved some issues I had with the gradient size bleeding out of the frame once the content size exceeded the frame.

Comment: @iSofia could you create a minimal xcode project with the code that you want to debug and share it?

Comment: You're right; I have, and it works. The logic or sequence in my routines must be undoing the gradient for some reason; *I'll keep working on it.* Thank you for your tireless help. In any case, I'll mark your answer as the accepted one.